# The requirements of gathering information data without any limits?

Tags: network, databases, vulnerability, account-security, information-gathering

It's a well known fact that phones, computers and other devices can be tracked and be used as a means of collecting user information if the situation permits it, for example in crime investigations. I don't know exactly how this is done, what technical methods that are used and one could think whether it's built-in back doors that are used or just a brute-force approach.

I think it's good to know in terms of personal data security and the ever growing demand for total control slowly becoming a reality which can be witnessed today in some parts of the world.

This is not about any laws because I'm well aware of the laws regarding this subject. What I didn't find information about is how someone can collect data or track a device without any limit distance-wise and to what extent this data collecting can occur without getting further help from other sources, for example if the suspicious person leaves the region/country.

When authorities tracks down criminals or gathers data for a case, is their method of retrieving this information only dependent on one source with complete access or do they contact various of different sources to help them achieve this? **Can anyone with enough knowledge use the these same methods or do they require certain accessibility that goes beyond that of an ordinary citizen?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question very broadly asks about "information gathering" in general. Only, there are lot of different sources for information with different amount of detail and different ways to get these information.

Sometimes all is needed is to combine public information in an intelligent way (e.g. monitor activity on social networks), sometimes hacking of devices like phone or computer helps, sometimes service providers will provide the data after some court order or similar. Thus, it depends on the kind, source and required detail of data if *"enough knowledge"* is sufficient or of *"certain accessibility"* is needed which ordinary citizens don't have.

And even if some information gathering requires *"certain accessibility"*  it might be possible for an ordinary citizen with enough money to pay knowledgeable criminals or bribe the right persons in order to get access to the information of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of gathering information about a cellular phone user, depending on what you're trying to gather.

But one method that has been getting press lately in [the U.S.](https://www.aclu.org/blog/free-future/police-citing-terrorism-buy-stingrays-used-only-ordinary-crimes) and [Canada](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/the-rcmp-surveilled-thousands-of-innocent-canadians-for-a-decade) is [IMSI catchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI-catcher), particularly [Stingrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_phone_tracker), which essentially act as a fake cell tower and slurp up data from phones that connect to them.  These cost [a few hundred thousand dollars](https://theintercept.com/surveillance-catalogue/stingray-iii/), which puts them out of the range of most civilians, and presumably the company producing them doesn't sell them to just anyone who has the money (but who knows?).